# Issue with Turtle in Python (AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'tracer')

Tags: python

I've been trying to follow this tutorial on creating pixel art in Turtle: https://www.101computing.net/pixel-art-in-python/

And I tried to copy over their code, but when I put it into VS Code, I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'tracer'

[Running their editor seems to work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjOYb.png)

Any ideas on what the issue could be? All I did was copy and paste the code (and fix some issues with indents).

```
#Pixel Art - http://www.101computing.net/pixel-art-in-python/

import turtle

myPen = turtle.Turtle()
myPen.tracer(0)
myPen.speed(0)
myPen.color("#000000")

# This function draws a box by drawing each side of the square and using the fill function
def box(intDim):
    myPen.begin_fill()
    # 0 deg.
    myPen.forward(intDim)
    myPen.left(90)
    # 90 deg.
    myPen.forward(intDim)
    myPen.left(90)
    # 180 deg.
    myPen.forward(intDim)
    myPen.left(90)
    # 270 deg.
    myPen.forward(intDim)
    myPen.end_fill()
    myPen.setheading(0)
    
boxSize = 10    
#Position myPen in top left area of the screen
myPen.penup()
myPen.forward(-100)
myPen.setheading(90)
myPen.forward(100)
myPen.setheading(0)

##Here is an example of how to draw a box   
#box(boxSize)

##Here are some instructions on how to move "myPen" around before drawing a box.
#myPen.setheading(0) #point to the right, 90 to go up, 180 to go to the left 270 to go down
#myPen.penup()
#myPen.forward(boxSize)
#myPen.pendown()

#Here is how your PixelArt is stored (using a "list of lists")

pixels     = [[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]]
pixels.append([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])
pixels.append([0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0])
pixels.append([0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0])
pixels.append([0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0])
pixels.append([1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1])
pixels.append([1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1])
pixels.append([1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1])
pixels.append([1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1])
pixels.append([1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1])
pixels.append([1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1])
pixels.append([1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1])
pixels.append([0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0])
pixels.append([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0])
pixels.append([0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])
pixels.append([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])

for i in range (0,len(pixels)):
    for j in range (0,len(pixels[i])):
      if pixels[i][j]==1:
        box(boxSize)
    myPen.penup()
    myPen.forward(boxSize)
    myPen.pendown() 
    myPen.setheading(270) 
    myPen.penup()
    myPen.forward(boxSize)
    myPen.setheading(180) 
    myPen.forward(boxSize*len(pixels[i]))
    myPen.setheading(0)
    myPen.pendown()
    
myPen.getscreen().update()
```

Comment: can you edit the code you have tried to the question?

Comment: Done, just added it now.

Edit: removing the .tracer() line does make it run, but yeah, trying to skip the animation entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#changes-since-python-2-6)

> **Changes since Python 2.6**
> The methods Turtle.tracer(), Turtle.window_width() and
> Turtle.window_height() have been eliminated. Methods with these names
> and functionality are now available only as methods of Screen.

The reason it works in their online IDE is that they have an older version of python.

You can use `turtle.tracer(0)`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I should have thought to check what version of Python they were on.

Thank you!